# Developing a multi-tenant application so that users can work in different organizations using different tabs in same browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application with ASP.NET MVC3. There users should be able to log into several organizations and they should be able to work in those organizations using different tabs of same browser.

I cannot achieve this using session object because when session is updated by one tab, other tabs also refers to that updated organization.

So can some one tell me an approach, that this is going to work.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

*I think this information will also be needed some one to answer this.*

> I have a home page that shows all the organizations that particular
>   user is working in. So he can go into those organization pages by
>   opening the link in a different tab. Then the session is updated to
>   new organization. Even the tasks doing in old tab, goes to the
>   organization in new tab.

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Why not create different user types? Your users would be able to access these different parts of the site based on privileges associated with their user type, instead of needing to keep multiple browser tabs open.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question Charmander. I have a home page that shows the organizations that particular user is working in. So he can go into those organization pages by opening the link in a different tab. Then the session is updated to new organization. Even the tasks doing in old tab, goes to the organization in new tab.

Comment: Would it be feasible to give each organization its own subdomain?

Comment: @Xavier: mmm.... yes, It can be helpful, if we can create sub domains dynamically in web server. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @LasanthaBandara - I haven't done it myself, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395325/dynamic-sub-domain-creation-with-php-in-a-linux-based-server).  It looks pretty simple - you just have to have your DNS record set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use DOM's `window.name` property to store data for each tab and your SSID to sync these data with each other.

You may use [Sessvars.js](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvars.js) as a helper library.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) for further info.