# Subdomain Domain using .htacces for every users

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon Ec2. 
I am not professional in .htaccess , i have referred following .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^([\w-]+).example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/example.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /example.com/$1?subdomain=%1 [LAST,QSA]
```

when i try to execute this `username.example.com` to `example.com/subdomain?id=username`

I am using EC2 amazon server.

1st issues is if i am trying to execute `username.example.com` then this domain is not getting resolved.

2nd issue the above htaccess is not working for me . If any one could solve this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using `.htaccess` file, you need to setup a wild card virtual host and then rewrite it to the URL you need.

This [**information**](http://blog.orite.com.au/web_development/2009-01-22/setting-up-wildcard-virtual-hosts-for-web-development-environment/) might be useful, you can also refer to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395325/dynamic-sub-domain-creation-with-php-in-a-linux-based-server).

Comment: I have tried the thing which is given in the link.. but not working

Comment: This is the way to do it there is no other way, did you restart the server \ apache after editing?

Comment: Yeah , i restarted the server